# Alternative to VSTS 2008 WEb tests to test JavaScript & Ajax

Tags: webtest

I've read repeatedly how VSTS 2008 Web testing can only test the post and post back between web pages and thus cannot test calling Java Script or Ajax.  Is there an alternative so that I can test if my dynamically filled controls (javascript) and dynamically populated drop down list (AJAX) can are functioning correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [coded ui test in visual studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726(VS.100).aspx)?